# How to execute RPC calls on all clients when this method sent from one client?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

How to execute RPC calls on all clients when this method sent from one client? Is it exists some solution in Unity netcode like RPCTargets.All in Photon?

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;

public class ExampleChangeSomething : NetworkBehaviour // ->Inherit from NetworkBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        UI_ChangeSomething();
    }


    //Attach this to the Button click or call this function from somewhere(e.g. I call this on Start)
    public void UI_ChangeSomething()
    {
        //Client Send command to the Server
        Cmd_ChangeSomething("Please Print this Text");
    }

    //Execute this on Server
    [Command]
    void Cmd_ChangeSomething(string _text)
    {
        //The server then tell every Clients to execute the "Rpc_ChangeSomething" Function
        Rpc_ChangeSomething(_text);
    }



    [ClientRpc]
    void Rpc_ChangeSomething(string _text)
    {
        ChangeSomething(_text);
    }


    //the logic that needs to be executed by Every Client
    private void ChangeSomething(string _text)
    {
        //your logic here.
        Debug.Log(_text); // every client will print "Please Print this Text" in their Console

    }
}
```